# How to Reset scrollbar to top of window

Tags: c#, winforms

I am working on a Winform app using .net 4.5.

In my project, I have a window that contains only a button.

WHen the window is displayed, I add lots of controls dynamically to the point that a scrollbar is needed.

Once the controls are added, I move the single button to the bottom of the controls in the window.

This step of moving the button to the bottom of the controls makes the window scroll to the bottom. I have tested this by not moving the button to the bottom of the form, and the scroll stays at the top.

I have tried "this.VerticalScroll.Value = 0;" both before and after setting the position of the button.

Here is the code so you can get a clearer idea of what I am attempting to do:

```
public SignoffSurvey(int task_id)
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        this.task_id = task_id;

        int form_top = 10;
        int question_num = 0;

        XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
        doc.Load(DBHandler.getSetting("files_directory") + "\\" + "questionaire.xml");

        foreach (XmlNode node in doc.SelectNodes("/Questions/Question"))
        {
            question_num++;

            string type = node.Attributes["type"].Value;
            int top = 0;

            Panel pnl = new Panel();
            pnl.AutoSize = true;
            pnl.Top = form_top;
            pnl.Left = 10;

            Label text_lbl = new Label();
            text_lbl.Top = top;
            text_lbl.AutoSize = true;
            text_lbl.Text = node["text"].InnerText;
            pnl.Controls.Add(text_lbl);

            top += text_lbl.Height + 5;

            if (type == "mc" || type == "mct")
            {
                XmlNode choices = node["choices"];
                Boolean fc = false;
                foreach (XmlNode choice in choices.ChildNodes)
                {
                    RadioButton rb = new RadioButton();
                    rb.AutoSize = true;
                    rb.Text = choice.InnerText;
                    rb.Top = top;
                    rb.Left = 10;
                    top += rb.Height + 5;
                    pnl.Controls.Add(rb);

                    if (!fc) // check first item.
                    {
                        fc = true;
                        rb.Checked = true;
                    }
                }
            }

            if (type == "mct" || type == "txt")
            {

                TextBox tb = new TextBox();
                tb.Multiline = true;
                tb.Width = 500;
                tb.Height = 250;
                tb.Top = top;
                tb.Left = 10;
                pnl.Controls.Add(tb);
                top += tb.Height + 5;
            }

            pnl.Height = top;
            this.Controls.Add(pnl);
            form_top += pnl.Height + 10;
        }

        this.VerticalScroll.Value = 0;
        this.save_btn.Top = form_top;


    }
```

HOw can I force the window vertical scroll to the top regardless of where this 1 button is moved to?

Answer (score 0):

Okie. For anyone with a similar issue, here is the reason for the problem and how to overcome it.

The problem appears to be that the single button is 'selected' by default on the window. So when the window launches, it scrolls to the position of the button.

I added this:

```
this.Controls[1].Select();
```

after adding all my controls.

You have to use [1] because the button already on the form is [0].